# Simple android App working on browser(ionic serve) but not on device and emulator

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I followed the ionic start and created a simple app.
When I am trying `ionic serve` app opens in browser and I am to see the home and list of items.
When I am trying `ionic cordova build android` , build get success and apk gets created inside platforms/android/… path.
After installing this apk on an android emulator or device, when I opens the app, it crashes and android shows Open again popup message.

I do not know what is the problem here. Please help.

Below are some info -

**>ionic info**

Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.6.0 (C:\Users\1231083\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
Ionic Framework : ionic-angular 3.9.2
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
Cordova Platforms : android 7.1.2
Cordova Plugins : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.3.1, (and 4 other plugins)

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\1231083\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
NodeJS : v10.11.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm : 6.5.0
OS : Windows 7

**>ionic cordova plugin ls**
com.salesforce 7.0.0 "SalesforceMobileSDK Plugins"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.3.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.0 "Whitelist"

Comment: Have you installed Forcedroid? https://www.npmjs.com/package/forcedroid

Comment: What exactly do you mean by crashing. Does the splash screen show? Are you getting any errors or just the "white screen of death"? Also have you used the Chrome Inspector to check for any errors inside your WebView?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem maybe in some cases you might try with

`$ ionic cordova platform rm android`

`$ ionic cordova platform add android`

this works in some cases